Seeking assistance with debug session breakpoint binding in VS Code
I'm encountering with an issue while debugging a Node application.
I can successfully run the application locally using the command yarn run serve:api. However, when I join a debug session, all breakpoints become unbound.
I have reviewed the launch.json configuration and it appears to be correct:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "nest:serve:debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "serve:api"],
      "restart": true
    }
  ]
}


I've been using this type of configuration
{
    "name": "nest:serve:debug",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
    "runtimeArgs": ["run", "serve:api"],
    "restart": true,
    "port": 5858
}

Change this in package.json
"serve:api": "node --inspect-brk=5858 ./server.js",

